# 'jthrow' isn't a type

Tags: flutter, dart

while building my flutter application for ios I get this error:

```
Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/provider-6.0.5/lib/src/provider.dart:343:7: Error: 'jthrow' isn't a type.


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
```

the code is fine and doesn't have any errors.
I've already tried to build another project with the provider package included and get the same error

Answer (score 1):

enter this command:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```